# Get OOM exception when sending message with a high speed with netty

Tags: java, out-of-memory, netty

I write a client with netty in order to send message at a high rate. 
By jConsole I see "old gen" is increasing, and finally it throws
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.
Are there some ways or configuration to avoid this exception
The following is my test code:

```
    import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
    import io.netty.channel.Channel;
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
    import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
    import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
    import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
    import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
    import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

    public class TestNettyTcp {
        private EventLoopGroup group;

        private Channel ch;

        /**
         * @param args
         * @throws SyslogSenderException
         * @throws TimeoutException
         * @throws ExecutionException
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws InterruptedException
         * @throws UnknownHostException
         */
        public static void main( String[] args )
            throws UnknownHostException, InterruptedException, IOException,  ExecutionException,  TimeoutException {
            new TestNettyTcp().testSendMessage();
        }

        public TestNettyTcp()
            throws InterruptedException {
            group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group( group ).channel( NioSocketChannel.class )
                // .option( ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, 10 * 64 * 1024 )
                .option( ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1048576 ).option( ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, 1048576 )
                .option( ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true ).handler( new NettyTcpSyslogSenderInitializer() );
            // Connect to a server.
            ChannelFuture future = b.connect( "192.168.22.70", 514 );
            future.awaitUninterruptibly();
            // Now we are sure the future is completed.
            assert future.isDone();

            if ( !future.isSuccess() ) {
                future.cause().printStackTrace();
            }
            else {
                ch = future.sync().channel();
            }
        }

        public void testSendMessage()
            throws InterruptedException, UnknownHostException, IOException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {

            ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup( "SendMessage" );
            for ( int k = 0; k < 10; k++ ) {
                Thread thread = new Thread( threadGroup, new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        String payLoad = "key=\"value\" key2=\"value2\" key3=\"value3\" Count:";

                        try {
                            for ( int j = 0; j < 100; j++ ) {
                                long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                for ( int i = 0; i < 20000; i++ ) {

                                    ch.writeAndFlush( payLoad + j + "_" + i + "\n" );
                                }
                                System.out.println( "\r<br>Excuted time : " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - a ) / 1000f
                                    + "seconde" );
                            }

                        }
                        catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally {
                            if ( ch != null ) {
                                ch.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } );
                thread.start();
            }

            while ( threadGroup.activeCount() > 0 ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep( 1000 );
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class NettyTcpSyslogSenderInitializer
        extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

        public NettyTcpSyslogSenderInitializer() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void initChannel( SocketChannel ch )
            throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast( new StringEncoder() );
        }
    }
```

The code can reproduce the problem quickly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are writing faster then the network stack can handle. Be aware it's all asynchronous... You want to stop writing once Channel.isWritable() returns false and resume once it returns true again. You can notified for this changes by override the channelWritabilityChanged(...) method in ChannelInboundHandler.